# How to show that $xy^{-1} \in G$ in this case?

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $G$ be a subset of $GL_2(\mathbb Z_5)$ of the form

$$\begin{pmatrix}
m & b\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

I want to show that $G$ is a subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb Z_5)$ I know that the multiplicative identity exists in $G$ and I calculated the inverse of the following element $$\begin{pmatrix}
n & a\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$ in $G$ and I found it to be $$\begin{pmatrix}
1/n & -a\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$ but I am wondering how can I be sure that $n \neq 0$ and what is $-a \in \mathbb Z_5$?

Also, someone suggested that I should only check the closure and there is no need to check that $xy^{-1} \in G,$ is this claim correct?If yes, why?

Comment: What does $1/n$ mean? Have you worked with $\Bbb Z_p$ before?

Comment: In general, if the group $G$ is finite, then to check that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ you only need to check closure - there is no need to check that $x \in H \Rightarrow x^{-1} \in H$.

Comment: What that person was referring to is the [finite subgroup test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Finite_Subgroup_Test).

Comment: Note that if $n=0$ then the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}n&a\\&1\end{pmatrix}$ will not be invertible, and hence will not live in $G$.

Comment: You should write $\Bbb Z/5$, or $\Bbb F_5$, since $\Bbb Z_5$ are often the $5$-adic integers.

Comment: @TedShifrin yes, I have long ago but now I do not know how to handle this situation. for me $1/n$ appears from calculating $1/det$ of the given matrix but still I do not know what does it mean in $\mathbb Z_p$

Comment: @DerekHolt you know I have never seen this test in any book, do you know a book that contains it?

Comment: @Shaun  you know I have never seen this test in any book, do you know a book that contains it?

Comment: @KentaS I know, that is why I wanted a guarantee that it is not 0.

Comment: @DietrichBurde sorry about that I will be more careful next time

Comment: See Theorem 3.3 of Gallian's, *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra (Eighth Edition)"*.

Comment: @Shaun thank u!!

Comment: @Emptymind The point is, if $G$ is finite, then each element $y \in G$ has finite order $o(y)$, and then $xy^{-1} = xy^{o(y)-1}$, so checking that $xy^{-1} \in G$ is equivalent to checking that $xy^{o(y)-1} \in G$, which follows from closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to answer your original question, you can't a priory be sure that $n\neq 0$. Indeed, $0$ is an element of $\mathbb{Z}_5$, so nothing is stopping it from appearing. However, you should easily be able to show that if $n = 0$, then the matrix doesn't belong to $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_5)$ (in fact you pretty much already proved that). Thus, since $H$ is a subset of $GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_5)$, you can rest assured that $n=0$ won't appear.

Yes, in the case of a finite subgroup, it is sufficient to check for closure. It's because for any element $x$, $x^k$ must be in $H$ for any $k$ (due to closer), but since the set is finite, the sequence $x^k$ can't keep generating new elements, so it must return to the identity eventually, and thus there is a $n_0$ such that $x\times x^{n_0} = e$. In your case, it is very easy to show by straightforward computation that closure holds, and thus $H$ is a subgroup.

Comment: If $\Bbb Z_5$ has the usual meaning of 5adic integers (and it was not intended to be $\Bbb Z/(5)$ instead), then our group is but infinite

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen by $\mathbb Z_5,$ I meant $\mathbb Z / 5 \mathbb Z$